# Automatic Failover without data replication

Tags: replication, sql-server-2012, failover

I have a need to be able to automatically failover my databases and most need data replication. However, one database does not need data replication and so, for performance reasons, we do not include that in the auto failover plan since it requires data replication. Is there a way to disable data replication for certain databases?

Comment: What technology are you currently using?  Failover Cluster Instance?  AlwaysOn Availability Groups?  SQL Server Replication?

Comment: Sql Server Replication/Mirroring - but may move to AlwaysOn Availability groups.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your comment, it sounds like you are looking to make the move to AlwaysOn Availability Groups.  The way that availability groups work is that you *choose* which databases are added to the availability group and are therefore part of the high availability implementation.

So in other words, if you want `Database1` and `Database2` to be highly available with automatic failover, then you configure a partner to have synchronous commit and be an auto failover partner, and when you create your availability group you add those two databases to the availability group.  But if you don't want `Database3` to be part of that topology, then you simply don't do anything with that database regarding the availability group.

Comment: but in this scenario would Database3 also failover (obviously without the data replicating)?

Comment: No, `Database3` isn't part of the availability group, so it is not "living" on the other replicas/servers.  So, no, it wouldn't be part of any failover with this layout.  Is that not the desired effect?

Comment: right - so what I need is Database3 to failover along with the others - but I don't want the data replicated for Database3.

Comment: Then put `Database3` in the same availability group.  You don't want the data replicated for this database?  Maybe I'm a bit confused, but then don't set up replication for that database.  If that's not what you mean, please define "replicated" and what in particular you mean by that.

Comment: By replication - I mean when it fails over the database it fails over to should be empty (it does not need the data). I will need data replicated for the other databases but not for this particular one. Am I am able to set it up to do this?

Comment: That's not possible with availability groups.  You're basically looking to just have the database structure (DDL) and not the data itself (DML)?  What are you going to gain out of that?  Either way, you might have to have a custom mechanism to push that out, I can't think of an easy native way to achieve that.

Comment: You could potentially use a DDL trigger on the non-mirrored database to update the design from the principal server to the mirror(s).  This would approximate the desired design.  Having said that, I agree @ThomasStringer - this question seems a bit on the strange side.

Comment: @ThomasStringer yes - essentially that is what I am looking for. Main reason is due to performance - replicating data on the one database is giving an unwanted performance overhead and its data I don't need to replicate. However, if my primary site goes down I need to have that one switch over when all my other dbs switch automatically.

Comment: any more thoughts on this?